# PHP SOAP Client connect

Tags: php, soap, client

i want to connect a SOAP Client (via PHP 7.4).

Data provided are
https://plc.post.at/Post.Webservice/ShippingService.svc?wsdl
Der HTTPS Endpoint:
https://plc.post.at/Post.Webservice/ShippingService.svc/secure

How can I connect the SOAP Client? I always get
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://plc.post.at/Post.Webservice/ShippingService.svc?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://plc.post.at/Post.Webservice/ShippingService.svc?wsdl"

```
$soap = new SoapClient('https://plc.post.at/Post.Webservice/ShippingService.svc?wsdl', $options); should connect but does not.
$options = array(
    'follow_location' => 1,
    'cache_wsdl' => 0,
    'allow_redirects' => true,
    'http_errors' => true,
    'decode_content' => true,
    'verify' => false,
    'cookies' => false,
    'idn_conversion' => false,
    // SSL Configuration
    'stream_context' => $context,    
    'trace' => 0,    
    'exceptions' => true,
    'ciphers' => 'RC4-SHA',
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create(array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true
        )
    )));
```

Comment: Probably unrelated: You are defining `stream_context` twice, you should remove one. Also: you are defining `$options` prior to connecting right?

Comment: Hi, you are ritght about the stream_context. Over the time I added any option I could find in the internet (stream-context twice :( ), but always tghe same error.
options are defined prior.
https://plc.post.at/Post.Webservice/ShippingService.svc?wsdl seems to refer to other xml-files if I open the adress in browser.
I am quite new to soap, I try to write a program that send shipping information to post services and gets a label in return. 
Austrian Post cannot help me with the php-syntax...

Comment: $client = new SoapClient('http://soap.amazon.com/schemas3/AmazonWebServices.wsdl');
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
Returns the same error. Could it be a malconfiguration of php?

Comment: Could you check if the openssl extension is enabled in your php installation? Enable it if it is not.

Comment: It is enabled.
I saved the wsdl-file locally in my hd, from there it works ?!